# Deploy Django 1.7 on Apache with mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache

I am a newbie in Django, trying to deploy an app into Apache 2.2 using mod_wsgi.
I have a mymapsite created in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs. Inside mymapsite, I have a mymap which is the app.

In my httpd.conf, I added:

```
WSGIPythonPath "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mymapsite/"

WSGIScriptAlias /mymap "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mymapsite/mymapsite/wsgi.py"
```

In my wsgi, I have:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append('C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mymapsite/mymapsite')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mymapsite.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am getting error:

```
(9)Bad file descriptor: don't know how to spawn child process: C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/mymapsite/mymapsite/wsgi.py
```

Please advice/

Comment: This question is off topic on Stackoverflow, which is aimed at _programming_ questions. Please ask on http://www.serverfault.com and delete here.

Comment: There is no Django 1.8 yet. Use the most recent release, 1.7.